# Yosemite downgrade

Tags: macos, downgrade

I really really don't like the look of Yosemite.

How do I downgrade back from Yosemite to another OS?

Comment: It sounds like you want to downgrade your OS. You can do this but please note that this will involve wiping your HDD. You will want to do an Internet Recovery, wipe the HDD and reinstall the base OS and upgrade to what you want from there.